# How can I implement a function to an eventlistener

Tags: javascript, dom

CSS:

```
.motionContainerMenu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
    border: 2px solid red
}


.motionTop{
    position:absolute;
    border:2px solid blue;
    background-color: red;
    height:10px;
    width:100%
}
```

Html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="transcript.php">Test one</a>
            <div class="motionContainerMenu">
                <div class="motionTop"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.php">TestTwo</a>
            <div id="motionContainerMenu">
                <div class="motionTop"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Javascript:

```
function focusMenu(x) {

    x.style.borderColor     = "#fff";
    x.style.height          = "30px";
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#555"
}

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".motionTop");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    elements[i].addEventListener( "mouseover", function() { focusMenu(x) } );
};
```

On the last line of code I want each .motionTop to act independently.I removed the focusMenu(x) and replaced it with an Alert. I used the alert to test out the code and it worked exactly how I wanted it to.  However, I can't figure out how to make that line of code to accept the focusMenu function. I am new to JavaScript (I did a lot of research before posting on here).
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What is the `x` you pass to `focusMenu` ? It's undefined, maybe you want `event.currentTarget`

Comment: The `x` is causing the focusMenu() method to not be executed. Try dropping your code into jsfiddle.net & running it there. You'll see the error right away. Removing it & adding a `debugger;` keyword into the focusMenu() code will show that the listener will work.

Comment: Ok thank you for looking over my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the `event` parameter to your `mouseover` event-listener then you can get the relevant element via `event.currentTarget`:

```
elements[i].addEventListener( "mouseover", function( event ) {
    focusMenu( event.currentTarget )
} );
```

I also recommend using `classList` instead of changing `style` properties directly, like so:

CSS:

```
.focused {
    border-color: #FFF;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
elements[i].addEventListener( "mouseover", function( event ) {
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('focused');
} );
```

Note that if you want the `.focused` class to be removed on `mouseout` then you don't need JavaScript at all, just use CSS `:hover`:

```
.motionTop:hover {
    border-color: #FFF;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

Comment: Also, I know I can use css,  but I want to learn more about JavaScript: )